# What is the meaning of "they contained of value" in this text?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context

The following were the terms of peace to which Jovian consented. First, the five provinces east of the Tigris, which had been ceded to Rome by Narses, the grandfather of Sapor, after his defeat by Galerius, were to be given back to Persia, with their fortifications, their inhabitants, and all that they contained of value.

https://www.gutenberg.org/files/16167/16167-h/16167-h.htm

Comment: Everything that they contained [which was] of value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There would be goods and produce of commercial value in the provinces. We could imagine the Romans loading up waggons with farm produce, bales of cloth, refined metal and taking it away before Persia regained control. In other situations a defeated army might even destroy these assets so denying them to the victor.

The agreement was that no such asset stripping should occur.